# Execute URL/Path in external program in Haxe

Tags: haxe, haxelib

It is possible to run URL or path with external program from Haxe?

Something like a Process.Start("C:\") in C# will be opened drive C in file windows explorer (or Process.Start("/home/user/Desktop") will open Caja with this path in Linux Mint), or somethink like a package "Open" in NodeJS (it will do the same).

Or I need to open some text file with text editor, what selected in system by default.
Or when I try to run URL, then must be opened default web-browser with this address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can do this little code:

```
public static function execUrl (url:String) : Void {
    switch (Sys.systemName()) {
        case "Linux", "BSD": Sys.command("xdg-open", [url]);
        case "Mac": Sys.command("open", [url]);
        case "Windows": Sys.command("start", [url]);
        default:
    }
}
```

in unix-like systems can be used program "xdg-open". it know how to run needed path/url, and in windows this can do program "start"

Comment: For completeness, we can use `Sys.command("open", [url]);` on Mac.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it does anything when you run your app on Android. `Sys.systemName()` returns `Linux` but `Sys.command(...)` doesn't launch the browser.

Comment: Maybe xdg-open is not available on Android, see example here: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=235733